# Can not get id from JSON by QueryParamqq

Tags: java, json, database

I want to get 2 id(id and manufacturer_id) from 2 table following as:
it's Ok and no problem, but if I change parameter of `id=661`. URL: http://localhost:9999/TestJersey/rest/test/getID?id=661&manufacturer_id=1

it seem occur error and I can not get any data from database.
This is my class:

This is my POJO

```
public class DetailManufacturer {

private Integer id; 
private String name;
private String price;
private Integer manufacturer_id;
private String manufacturer_name;

public DetailManufacturer() {

}

public DetailManufacturer(Integer id, String name, String price, Integer manufacturer_id, String manufacturer_name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    this.manufacturer_id = manufacturer_id;
    this.manufacturer_name = manufacturer_name;
}
public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getPrice() {
    return price;
}
public void setPrice(String price) {
    this.price = price;
}
public Integer getManufacturer_id() {
    return manufacturer_id;
}
public void setManufacturer_id(Integer manufacturer_id) {
    this.manufacturer_id = manufacturer_id;
}
public String getManufacturer_name() {
    return manufacturer_name;
}
public void setManufacturer_name(String manufacturer_name) {
    this.manufacturer_name = manufacturer_name;
}
```

I have debug and see that line:

```
if(detailManufacturer.getId() == id && detailManufacturer.getManufacturer_id() == manufacturer_id)
```

it's seem this line incorrect, please support me, thanks so much...

Comment: Please mention where and what error you are getting!

Comment: with URL:  http://localhost:9999/TestJersey/rest/test/getID?id=1&manufacturer_id=1, I can get id and manufacturer_id, but with:  http://localhost:9999/TestJersey/rest/test/getID?id=661&manufacturer_id=1, I can't get id and manufacturer_id

Comment: I think it occur this line:  if(detailManufacturer.getId() == id && detailManufacturer.getManufacturer_id() == manufacturer_id)

Comment: Please post the `DetailManufacturer` class

Comment: or maybe you do not have a `Car` and `Manufacturer` for `661` && `1`

Comment: Hi guy, I have added DetailManufacturer class

Comment: Yes debug and see what's happening at that line, also check your DB if you have record  with this ID.

Comment: yes, If I assign id = 1 and manufacturer_id =1 or id=2 and manufacturer_id=2, It's Ok, but id=661 and manufacturer_id=1, it occur error, and I can not get result from json

Comment: `I can not get result from json`  I do not believe that the records exist in the DB, but if you are sure, then show the JSON that is produced for `661`

Comment: You can review below output result

Comment: You should edit your question with this information. BUT anyway, you were trying to select using 661 and 1 but this data clearly shows that it should be `661` and `4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

those are output result log

ID(CARID) | NAME | PRICE | MANUFACTURER_ID | MANUFACTURER_NAME

```
1  Cho thue xe Honda  20000  1  Honda
2  Cho thue xe Honda  10000  2  Toyota
3  Cho thue xe Honda  30000  3  Huyndai
4  Cho thue xe Honda  66000  4  BMV
643  Cho thue xe Huyndai  200000  3  Huyndai
661  Cho thue xe Huyndai  150000  4  BMV
642  Cho thue xe Huyndai  210000  2  Toyota
641  Cho thue xe Huyndai  66000  1  Honda
607  Cho thue xe Mescedes  210000  6  Kia Morning
610  Cho thue xe Mescedes  200000  7  Luxus
621  Cho thue xe Mescedes  150000  5  Mercedes
581  Cho thue xe Mescedes  200000  4  BMV
546  Cho thue xe Toyota2   000002  5  Mercedes
547  Cho thue xe Toyota1  210000  6  kia Morning
548  Cho thue xe Toyota2  400000  7  Luxus
549  Cho thue xe Toyota3  500000  1  Honda
550  Cho thue xe Toyota4  300000  2  Toyota
551  Cho thue xe Toyota5  3233333  3  Huyndai
```

However, JSON don't have result and this is alert: The response was empty

Comment: You should edit your question with this information.  BUT anyway, you were trying to select using `661` and `1` but this data clearly shows that it should be `661` and `4`

Comment: Im sorry, maybe I confused, I will change my question. But I don't understand I set id = 661 and manufacturer_id = 4, it's still unsuccessful :((

Comment: Really the proper way should be to change your sql select statement to query by id and manufacturer_id

Comment: I think so, do you have any other solution about SQL for me ? I have posted full source code for you

Comment: I think that you are not using the latest version of your code.  Rebuild and re-deploy

Comment: Ok, I will try again and inform result for you

Comment: I have only a version and I not yet fixed :(